# how to get error status code from error object

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

i was doing my `try catch`es and assinging all error status codes as `500` and i want to know if is it possible to get error status code for example inside catch block, like this:

instead of this

```
catch(err){
    return res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message
    })
}
```

this:

```
catch(err){
    return res.status(err.statusCode).send({
        message: err.message
    })
}
```

i checked docs but there is no word about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this err inherits from **Error** class then its not possible. You can implement a wrapper in order to associate thrown errors with status 500.
See https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/errors.html#errors_errors

Answer (score 0):

You can't do 'err.statusCode'. [Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) object doesn't have any property named 'statusCode'.

Basically, you have to identify what http [statusCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) should be sent from server based on your outcome of the execution.